# Dealing with multiple apps overriding management commands in Django

Tags: python, django

I've got an issue where there's more than one app trying to override the same management command in a Django project.

1. Are there sensible ways to deal with this?
2. Which gets priority - the app the was defined first in `INSTALLED_APPS`, or the one that was defined last?
3. Is it possible to effectively subclass the most recently defined management command rather than simply replacing it?

For context I'm trying to get `django_pdb` (see [github](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-pdb)) to work more nicely with `south` and `django.contrib.staticfiles`.

Comment: Why are you renaming existing management commands?  Please don't do that.  Please provide unique names for your commands and avoid this problem.

Comment: I think it's a pretty reasonable thing to want to do given the context.  (Adding --pdb options to the existing test and runserver commands)  Apps such as `south` and `django.contrib.staticfiles` do exactly that, so I'm not sold on a blanket "don't do that" response.

Comment: @SLOTT if the code is completely in developer control, this is a very silly question -- you just rename one of them.  I think he is trying to ask what to do when you use two community apps that both provide "load_sample_data" commands.

Comment: Renaming one of the commands is fine, but it's not very elegant if what you're trying to do is extend an *existing* command.

Comment: can you extend and rename?  ./manage.py south-syncdb and ./manage.py pdb-syncdb?

Comment: @tomc django management commands are classes, you can subclass the command class and then rename the module (my_command -> my_nice_command). I agree with S. Lott, renaming existing management commands should be avoided.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli - Sure you can subclass, but how do you know which to subclass?  If you're writing a reusable app, you won't know what other apps will be installed in projects that use your app.

Comment: @tomc: "it's a pretty reasonable thing to want ".  Future administrators will, however, likely hate you for the confusion created by having a new command that doesn't do what they think it should do.

Comment: Future administrators won't care about overriden runserver that just gives extra options. Renaming doesn't help since the apps like staticfiles or south subclass original runserver command not the custom-named one.

Answer (score 3):

2.5 years later, but in case someone has the same problem and lands here after a google search, I've made a small django app to deal with that case: django-mcmo ('Management Command Multiple Override'), available on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mcmo). It has limitations but works as expected.

Works with django 1.4 to 1.8 and py 2 and 3, contributions welcome on [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/django-mcmo).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest answer I'm aware of is: structure your project so you can change one of them and keep a record of your changes so you can apply it to future releases.

For my projects I like to have:

```
/myproject
  /lib
    /app1
    /app2
    /app3
```

Then explicitly add /lib to the path in setup.py

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import sys
lib_dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'lib')
if lib_dir not in sys.path[:4]:
    sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'lib'))
```

I'm probably far more likely than average to take an app, install it, then change 10% of it to work exactly how I want.

The advantage of this is: 1) most dependencies ship with the code and are tracked in GIT 2) no chance for a system wide change to unexpectedly cause bugs in an app if you are running multiple apps from the same machine and 3) Easy to change, with revision history, any and everything in the app.

Not having dove too deeply into south's management commands, and never having used django_pdb, your particular problem might not be solved with the "make a local copy and rename one of them" approach, but I share in case it might.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That might be fine if you're working on an individual project, but it doesn't help if your writing a reusable app that you want others to install.  (Such as in my use case)